# Restrict Input when time.sleep is running in python?

Tags: python, input, time, sleep

Is there a way to restrict user to input something in the console while `time.sleep` is running?

I tried this code and its working but i wondered if there is another way to do this:

```
import threading
import os
import time
import sys


print("Wait a moment")
def clearer():
    c = 0
    d = 5000
    while d != c:
        print("         ", end="")
        time.sleep(0.001)
        print("\r = ", end="")
        c += 1

a = threading.Thread(target=clearer, args=())
a.start()
a.join()
os.system('clear')
print("Good Job")
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Another Way**
Yeah I find another way...
It's by using curses modules

```
import time
import curses
import os

screen = curses.initscr()

def stop(curse):
    curses.curs_set(0)
    print("Wait a moment...")
    time.sleep(2)
    curses.flushinp()

curses.wrapper(stop)
os.system('clear')
curses.curs_set(1)
print("Thanks you for waiting")
a = input("Type something: ")
curses.wrapper(stop)
os.system('clear')
print(a)
```

--- Using pydroid3 on android